# How to get username at end of url using slug

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I'm trying to get the users username at the end of the 'my-profile' url , I have used autoslug on url ("users/") and this is working fine for 'profile_view' , but it's not working with 'my_profile' , can you tell me what I'm doing wrong.

At the moment i'm getting error: NoReverseMatch at /
Reverse for 'my_profile' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['my\-profile/(?P[^/]+)$']

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('feed.urls')),
    path('users/', user_views.users_list, name='users_list'),
    path('users/<slug>/', user_views.profile_view, name='profile_view'),
    path('friends/', user_views.friend_list, name='friend_list'),
    path('users/friend-request/send/<str:username>/', user_views.send_friend_request, name='send_friend_request'),
    path('users/friend-request/cancel/<str:username>/', user_views.cancel_friend_request, name='cancel_friend_request'),
    path('users/friend-request/accept/<str:username>/', user_views.accept_friend_request, name='accept_friend_request'),
    path('users/friend-request/delete/<int:id>/', user_views.delete_friend_request, name='delete_friend_request'),
    path('users/friend/delete/<int:id>/', user_views.delete_friend, name='delete_friend'),
    path('edit-profile/', user_views.edit_profile, name='edit_profile'),
    path('my-profile/<slug>', user_views.my_profile, name='my_profile'),
    path('search_users/', user_views.search_users, name='search_users'),
]
```

models.py

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(default='default.png',   upload_to='profile_pics')
    slug = AutoSlugField(populate_from='user')
    bio = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    friends = models.ManyToManyField('Profile', blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.user.username)

    
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return "/users/{}".format(self.slug)
```

views.py

```
@login_required
def profile_view(request, slug):
    p = Profile.objects.filter(slug=slug).first()
    u = p.user
    sent_friend_requests = FriendRequest.objects.filter(from_user=p.user)
    rec_friend_requests = FriendRequest.objects.filter(to_user=p.user)
    user_posts = Post.objects.filter(user_name=u)

    friends = p.friends.all()

    # is this user our friend
    button_status = 'none'
    if p not in request.user.profile.friends.all():
        button_status = 'not_friend'

        # if we have sent him a friend request
        if len(FriendRequest.objects.filter(
            from_user=request.user).filter(to_user=p.user)) == 1:
                    button_status = 'friend_request_sent'
        


        # if we have received a friend request 
        if len(FriendRequest.objects.filter(
            from_user=p.user).filter(to_user=request.user)) == 1:
                    button_status = 'friend_request_received'
        


    context = {
            'u': u,
            'button_status': button_status,
            'friends_list': friends,
            'sent_friend_requests': sent_friend_requests,
            'rec_friend_requests': rec_friend_requests,
            'post_count': user_posts.count
    }

    return render(request, 'users/profile.html', context)

@login_required
def my_profile(request, slug):
        user = Profile.objects.filter(slug=slug)
        p = request.user.profile
        you = p.user
        sent_friend_requests = FriendRequest.objects.filter(from_user=you)
        rec_friend_requests = FriendRequest.objects.filter(to_user=you)
        user_posts = Post.objects.filter(user_name=you)
        friends = p.friends.all()

        # is this user our friend
        button_status = 'none'
        if p not in request.user.profile.friends.all():
            button_status = 'not_friend'

            # if we have sent him a friend request
            if len(FriendRequest.objects.filter(
                from_user=request.user).filter(to_user=you)) == 1:
                        button_status = 'friend_request_sent'
            

            if len(FriendRequest.objects.filter(
                from_user=p.user).filter(to_user=request.user)) == 1:
                        button_status = 'friend_request_received'
        

        context = {
                'u': you,
                'button_status': button_status,
                'friends_list': friends,
                'sent_friend_requests': sent_friend_requests,
                'rec_friend_requests': rec_friend_requests,
                'post_count': user_posts.count
        }
        return render(request, 'users/profile.html', context)
```

layout.html

```
  <a class="nav-item" href="{% url 'home' %}">HOME</a>
  <a class="nav-item" href="{% url 'users_list' %}">ADD NEW FRIENDS</a>
  {% if user.is_authenticated %}
    <a class="nav-item" href="{% url 'friend_list' %}">FRIENDS</a> 
    <a class="nav-item" href="{% url 'my_profile' %}">PROFILE</a> 
    <a class="nav-item" href="{% url 'post-create' %}">CREATE POST</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
path('my-profile/<slug:slug>', user_views.my_profile, name='my_profile')
```

The format goes `<path-converter:variable-name>`. You had the path converter `slug` but not the variable name that corresponded to your view function `my_profile(request, slug)`.

Although the error you are getting is because when django renders a template it has to convert all template tags to html etc. It is trying to resolve `{% url 'my_profile' %}` but you haven't given it the `'slug'` argument.

Try

```html
<a class="nav-item" href="{% url 'my_profile' u.profile.slug %}">PROFILE</a>
```

Comment: I tried this and i'm still getting the same error as mentioned above

Answer (score 0):

You should pass `slug` to `url` tag in addition to namespace:

```
<a class="nav-item" href="{% url 'my_profile' slug=user.slug %}">PROFILE</a>
```

Also `slug` itself in `urls.py` should be in a format of type:name:

```
path('my-profile/<slug:slug>/', user_views.my_profile, name='my_profile'),
```

I advice you to read about [path-converters](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/http/urls/#path-converters) mentioned on previous answer.